# Show which record was updated by using trigger

Tags: database, plsql, triggers, dml

I am a freshmen in PL/SQL and a have such a problem:

I want to create a trigger that shows surname of the person, whose tel number was updated

what I have done

```
Set SERVEROUTPUT ON

Create or replace trigger inform
after update of scontact_number on SUPLIER
for each row
DECLARE 
x SUPLIER.ssurname%TYPE;
BEGIN
Select SSURNAME
into x
from SUPLIER;
dbms_output.put_line('New tel number for ' || x);
END;
/ 

UPDATE SUPLIER
SET SCONTACT_NUMBER = 6765092654
WHERE ID_SUPLIER = 1;
```

trigger was compiled, but when I had tried to fire it, I got an error 'table is mutating'

How can I fix it? 
I will be grateful for any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a table reference in the trigger.  Just use `:new`:

```
Create or replace trigger inform
after update of scontact_number on SUPLIER
for each row
DECLARE 
    x SUPLIER.ssurname%TYPE;
BEGIN
    Select :new.SSURNAME
    into x
    from dual;

    dbms_output.put_line('New tel number for ' || x);
END;
/
```

Or, more simply:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('New tel number for ' || :new.SSURNAME);
END;
```

And no variable is required.

Comment: Regarding your first code snippet - I believe, according to the best practices, it's better to simply assign the value to the variable (`x := :new.SSURNAME;`) rather than switching the PL/SQL - SQL context (`SELECT .. INTO`).